# apollo graphql federation server, load balancer health checks fail

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, amazon-elb, apollo-federation

I have a project which contains 6 graphql subgraphs and one gateway (express server) that federates those and connects to those. I have deployed this project on aws, each of those servers represents an ECS task and a load balancer attached to it. All of the graphql servers are up and running, but gateway is failing because of health checks.

I get the logs that server has started, but after that, load balancer performs health checks and the ecs task fails and starts over.

I don't know how to debug this because the health check configurations (path, status etc.) are correct and calling the health check path on local succeeds.

What am I missing and how can I set everything up? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey, I'm having a similar situation. I have a GraphQL server running with Apollo and am having an issue with health checks on the target groups for the application load balancer. Are you still facing this blocker?

Comment: @ImranSandozi hello, the problem I had was because it was configured to bind the server listener port to the loopback interface, which works great for local development without docker, but wouldn't work within docker because it would not listen on the bridge interface. So I have added `ENV PORT 8080` and `ENV HOST 0.0.0.0` to the dockerfile